# Image and Text View errors on Android XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

**https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/HN3FW3mfQlcokPsqmRvB2DZkmO4FGPSRRSIkYFnLItsnmG2rLdfC7d8rbJT7kbkudIn7Rp2aWrjHh-8=w1340-h587-rw**

I'm making an app (in Android Studio) and some weird errors are occurring, such as a large space left before the image and the text appearing on top of the image. I have researched but no solutions helped.

CONTENT.XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:text="Welcome!"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

PS< I also have another problem with the Navigation Drawer template in Android Studio, where when clicking the Example Action button the transparent circle that appears is squared off on one side. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It looks exactly as I described

Comment: Without seeing it visually, this is a difficult thing to address. Please add a screenshot.

Comment: Sure, I am just posting a shot :)

Comment: Image is the link at the top, I have not enough reputation to add images lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding your components into a `LinearLayout` and centering that within its parent `RelativeLayout`.

*Example:*

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/section_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Welcome!"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="35dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @OllyScargill No worries, also - do you need that `ScrollView`?

Comment: Also, how come the image is so big? I can't make it smaller

Comment: I do need scroll view! lol, also my image is fine now in linear layout! thanks!

Comment: If the image is really large, try playing with `android:scaleType`. `fitCenter` seems to work well for me most of the time.

Comment: Do you know anything about the android drawer navigator? The action bar has a drop down button, but the text in that drop down is always black and I cannot get it to go white like the rest.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are using a Relative Layout. I suggest to you to encapsulate the Textview and the Imageview inside an LinearLayout with vertical orientation. I hope that it help you.

Comment: I think it would work, but you only need a Scrollview if you want to display more content that fits the screen

Comment: Yes, I want dynamic content influenced by a feed

Comment: Yes, It would work. You have to create the views with the content and insert them inside the LinearLayout or directly inside the ScrollView.